# JAX-RS: Multiple paths

Tags: java, jax-rs

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

public class xxx
{
  @GET
  @Path(value = "path1")
  public Response m1()
  {
    ...
  }

  @GET
  @Path(value = "path2")
  public Response m1()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using RESTEasy btw.

Comment: I assume you want two paths to go to the same method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

yes you can do that although you will have to rename your methods so that their signature is different.

**Update:** *Check Dieter Cailliau's answer,* `@Path("/{a:path1|path2}")` *is probably what you want...*

```
public class BlahResource{
    @GET
    @Path("path1")
    public Response m1(){
        return Response.ok("blah").build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("path2")
    public Response m2(){
        return this.m1();
}
```

you can check JSR-311's API and it's reference implementation named "jersey" there:

[JSR311 API](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/index.html)

[Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)

Comment: It is also possible using resteasy?

Comment: Actually there is no reason your answer is not a good one, in fact I would argue that it's better than most here, because those two methods can delegate to a single service responsible for doing the work. That makes your codes much more maintainable.

Answer (score 95):

```
@Path("/{a:path1|path2}")
```

From resteasy docs:
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings

Comment: If anyone is interested I tried this with jersey (jax-rs) and it worked.

Comment: @Path regular expression support is specified in the JAX-RS (JSR-339) specification (at least in version 2.0), so any implementation should support it.

Comment: If you're using composite path, I'll have to escape slashes like {a:path1\\/subPath1|path2\\/subPath2}

Comment: Do you know how I can make that slash "/" optional? It means either it matches "/abc" or doesn't match.

Comment: I want to match either "/" or "/path".

Answer (score 13):

Some extra details about Path annotation...

As a previous responses state, regular expressions to be used with in the annotated path declaration mapping:

```
{" variable-name [ ":" regular-expression ] "}
```

You can declare multiple paths, but there is also a path hierarchy that was not immediately obvious to me whereby the class annotated path prefixes the following method path annotations. One might write the following class for a concise multiple path option which could be useful for resource versioning perhaps.

```
@Path("/{a:v1|v2}")
@Produces("text/*")
public class BlahResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/blah")
    public Response m1() {
        return Response.ok("blah").build();
    }
}
```

Please note the fact that the class "BlahResource" has been declared with the path "/v1" or "/v2" making the resource accessible as:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/v1/blah
blah
```

and also

```
$ curl localhost:8080/v2/blah
blah
```

Comment: The, somewhat confusing, JAX-RS API spec can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html#value--

Comment: It is not supported by swagger at the moment https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

You could use sub resources to map two paths to the same resource:

```
public class MySubResource {
    @GET
    public Response m1() {
        return Response.ok("blah").build();
    }
}

@Path("/root")
public class MyRootResource {

    @Path("/path1")
    public MySubResource path1() {
        return new MySubResource();
    }

    @Path("/path2")
    public MySubResource path2() {
        return new MySubResource();
    }
 }
```