# Jax-rs (Wink) multiple GET methods throwing 404 or 405

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, apache-wink

I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784028/jax-rs-multiple-paths) but not the same as my problem.

I am building an Apache Wink application and I have a resource class like this..

```
@Path("/things")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public class ThingResource extends AbstractResource {
  ...
}
```

My first GET method is intended to be the basic get-collection method that is called in response to ... www.example.com/context/things.  It looks like the following

```
@GET
public List <Thing> getThings() {
  ...
}
```

My second GET method is supposed to get a specific Thing returned by getThings(), it looks like the below

```
@GET
@Path("/{thingId}")
public Thing getThing (@PathParam ("thingId") long id) {
 ...
}
```

---

Up to this point, everything is working just fine.

---

So, when I add another GET method, intended to create a file representation of a specific Thing from the collection returned by the getThings() -- (It is as below) -- I get a 404 error when I try to hit the [get /] => getThings()

```
@GET
@Path("/{thingId}/export")
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response exportThing( @PathParam ("thingId") long thingId, @DefaultValue("true") boolean encryptFile) {
  ...
}
```

If I remove the exportThing() method and redeploy it, it runs fine.

Tomcat 6
Java 6
Apache Wink 1.2

Comment: You have an extra parameter in your `exportThing`, with a 'dangling' @DefaultValue annotation. I'd remove those.

Comment: Must the params (qty) match the path? My intention was that the thingId would be passed in (required), the string "/export" would follow, and the encryptFile would be optional. Can I handle that optional case or should I overload exportThings() with URI Patterns that exactly match the method sig?
  
    `@GET  @Path("/{thingId}/export")
public Response exportThing(@PathParam("thingId") long thingId )  { ... }`  
---
    `@GET  @Path("/{thingId}/export/{encryptFile}")
public Response exportThing(@PathParam("thingId") long thingId, @PathParam("encryptFile") boolean encryptFile )  { ... }`

Comment: Yes, use the override strategy. Your current method doesn't do what you think it does (it maps the @PathParam, then attempts to deserialize the request body into the `encryptFile` parameter).

Comment: You had it right @Perception, I refactored it and it works fine now.