# Java JAX-RS How to implement a GET API with query and normal request

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I am learning JAX-RS, as an activity, I have created an endpoint which will list out all the TODO within by DB.

```
@Path("list")
@GET
public List<Todo> getTodos(){
    return todoService.getTodos();
}
```

The end point URL is

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list
```

Currently it lists all the TODO items, Since, I am learning query params I have decided to add add  a condition to and list out only completed TODO items.

The end point URL is

```
http://localhost:9090/hello-todo/api/v1/todo/list?taskstatus=completed
```

The implementation method which I have written is
@Path("list")
@GET
public List getFilteredTodos(@QueryParam("taskstatus") String taskstatus_){
return todoService.getFilteredTodos();
}

The build is fine, but while deploying it throws the below error:

```
The application resource model has failed during application initialization.

[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public java.util.List academy.learnprogramming.rest.TodoRest.getTodos() and public java.util.List academy.learnprogramming.rest.TodoRest.getFilteredTodos(java.lang.String) at matching regular expression /list. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@8bd9d08']
```

I get that the deployement has failed as the both are having the same URI but how do I handle such a scenario?

Possible Solution:

```
@Path("list")
@GET
public List<Todo> getFilteredTodos(@QueryParam("taskstatus") String taskstatus_){
    if (taskstatus_!=null && !taskstatus_.isEmpty()) {
        return todoService.getFilteredTodos(taskstatus_);
    }else{
        return todoService.getTodos();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:
Implement one method with @Path("list") and handle the case with an empty taskstatus parameter value inside

Comment: I have  updated the question with a solution above. Is my implementation correct?

Comment: You should also pass the `taskstatus` parameter to see which filter will you apply.

Comment: @alexandrum you mean the path should be corrected to @Path("list/{taskStatus}) wont this act as a parameter?.

Comment: No, I mean the line with `return todoService.getFilteredTodos();`, you should also pass the parameter received such as: `return todoService.getFilteredTodos(taskStatus);`

Comment: @alexandrum thanks for pointing that out.  I let me go and fix those code changes!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like:

```
 @GET
   @Path("list/{taskStatus}")
   public List getFilteredTodos(@PathParm("taskStatus") String taskStatus) {
      // do the filtering
   }
```

So you will have a different path that will not be conflicted with the main one. 
More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6896897/4333961) and [here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings).

Comment: taskstatus is a query parameter. But here we are handling it as a parameter.

Comment: I understand, I just wanted to offer you another perspective. If it is mandatory to be a query parameter then you can go with the solution proposed by @skydriver and handle both cases within one method by checking the parameter received.

Comment: It should be a query parameter.